# OFDMA RU allocation

Tags: wifi

I am studying 802.11ax OFDMA feature recently.
I read some paper about OFDMA feature , I was wondering how does AP decide how many of RU would be allocated for STAs that are going to transmit with UL OFDMA ? and what RU size should be allocated for each STA , could it be different for each STA ?
e.g. STA1 get 52 tones , STA2 get 26 tones , STA3 get 106 tones ....

Also , there are BSRP & BSR packet before AP send trigger frame , 
what does the buffer status mean ?
Is it the buffer size of the packet ? or data length in MSDU ? 
Would it influence how large the RU size to be allocated for STAs by AP ?

[image]

I really want to figure out  these problems , I will appreciate if anyone can answer these questions.

Thanks.

Comment: This topic is not really programming related. I'd suggest you to try https://electronics.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

> what does the buffer status mean?

Since for OFDMA some centralized control is required for uplink especially, AP requests BSR for the clients. The clients then send the AP their respective details about the number of packets in their uplink queue and other details. It's not specifically mentioned in the standard rather left for the companies and wifi alliance.

> Would it influence how large the RU size to be allocated for STAs by
>   AP ?

That too is left for the manufacturers, however, there are some papers that suggest that not only the RU size but also the individual subcarriers in the RU to be determined based on the subchannel condition and power constraint for each client. For this, the AP will also need Channel State Information.